# Immediately see "Changes not staged for commit" after git clone

Tags: git, github

I'm working with a team of developers who are all working on different machines. I happen to be working on a Mac and immediately after cloning any of our repos, I see:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/MoreDirectory/AFile.txt
modified:   SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/DifferentDirectory/AFile.cs
...
```

And a list of about another 60 files after doing a `git status`.

I've tried messing with various config related things and after running `git conflig -l` I see:

```
core.excludesfile=/Users/myname/.gitignore_global
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
user.name=My Name
user.email=myemail@email.com
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=false
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/MyCompany/RepoName.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I've tried `git reset --hard` / `git clean -f -d`, even just manually doing a `git checkout -- <file>` on each of them and nothing seems to make these "modified" files go away.

When running `git diff` I see the following for each file:

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/DifferentDirectory/AFile.cs.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you run `git config core.autcrlf`, what do you get?

Comment: I have `core.autocrlf=true` in my list after running `git config -l` (I actually _just_ tried this which is why it wasn't in my original post)

Comment: (Sorry I meant `git config core.autocrlf`; the "o" was missing). The reason why it doesn't get listed in the output of `git config -l` is probably that this key-value pair is present in your user-wide or system-wide Git config file, as opposed to the repo's config file. What does `git config --global core-autocrlf` tell you?

Comment: `error: key does not contain a section: core-autocrlf`

Comment: Sorry again, I meant `git config --global core.autocrlf` (a period, not a hyphen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` causes file endings to be converted from `<LF>` to `<CRLF>` when you check them out. Since you are on a Mac, which uses `<LF>`, you probably don't want that setting. From the behavior you are seeing, it looks like you probably have settings in your `.gitattributes` file that handles the `<LF>`/`<CRLF>` translation, so try setting your `core.autocrlf` to `false`, check out the project again, and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Just a remark: on a Mac, setting `core.autcrlf` to `false` or `input` sounds reasonable, but I think it makes more sense to use that setting at the user-level (`git config --global ...`), rather than on a per-repo basis.